# Retrieve the data visible in the fields on the current position

Tags: qgis, qfield

I would like to retrieve the values of the X, Y coordinates and the elevation of the point (located at the bottom left) and inject them into the form of the point attribute. What variables should I use?
[image: Screen shot QField]

Comment: on qfield 2.6.3 Gecko and Qgis 3.22.16

Answer (score 0):

You really should show some effort to have researched your question before asking - but the answer is $x, $y, $z